# Change contents of new message in outlook

Tags: macos, outlook, automation, applescript

I wan to change the content of the currently composed message and add the string `*WF*` at the end. Below is the script, I get an error `Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t set content of draft window id 9490 to ...`

```
on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    activate

    set theWindow to window 1

    -- check it's really draft
    if class of theWindow is not draft window then
        display dialog "Not a draft"
        return
    end if

    -- save the draft
    save theWindow

    --get the id of the object of the draft window
    set myObjectID to id of (object of theWindow)

    -- to make it secure
    set myContent to content of message id myObjectID

    --edit recipient
    -- set theBCC to bcc recipient of message id myObjectID
    -- set emailString to theBCC
    make new bcc recipient at message id myObjectID with properties {email address:{name:"Ittay Dror", address:"idror@akamai.com"}}

    set myContent to my replace_chars(myContent, "</body>", "*WF*</body>")
    set the content of theWindow to myContent
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't set the content of a window. Please set the content of the message:

```
set the content of message id myObjectID to myContent
```

Cheers,
Michael / Hamburg

Comment: But then the contents of the window stay the same. is there a way to read from the message?

Comment: **close theWindow**
before the last **end tell** saves the content. I didn't find any other way... If you want to do something else with the message, you can open it again with
    **open message id myObjectID**